# Protect android devices

Tags: android

Is there a way to protect android devices so that the

- user is no more able to download/install other apps?

The idea is to lend devices with specific apps.

Ideally the owner (that's me) should be able to remove the protection using a password/passphrase

Comment: its possible by creating an app. if your uninstall that app !??? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileasap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, don't think it can be done on a stock device.

If there is a way it is probably within the [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Likely though is that if you want to achieve this you'd need at least a rooted device, and maybe even your own custom build of the OS to allow for it.